# How to replace letters in SQL table with TSQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have to replace letter R for DR in every record from column Name.

```
SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Department
WHERE Name LIKE 'R%'
GO
```

I know how to find this letter, now question is how to replace it?
I tried

```
SELECT REPLACE ('R%', 'R', 'DR')
```

Even if its valid, i dont know where excacly should I put it?

Correct answer

```
SELECT REPLACE(name, 'R', 'DR') as name_without_r, * 
FROM HumanResources.Department
WHERE Name LIKE 'R%'
GO
```

Comment: Just use:  `replace(name, 'R', 'DR')`

Comment: @GordonLinoff Where in this query should i place "replace"? Never used it before (ik it might be funny)

Comment: [REPLACE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: `LIKE 'R%'` will only match strings that _start_ with `'R'`. The pattern needs to be `'%R%'` to match the letter anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(name, 'R', 'DR') as name_without_r, * 
FROM HumanResources.Department
WHERE Name LIKE 'R%'
GO
```

Thing is, that will replace every R in the whole name.. If it's not what you want, but instead want to change the R at the start, into DR, perhaps this instead:

```
SELECT CONCAT('D', name) as name_starting_r_changed_to_dr, * 
FROM HumanResources.Department
WHERE Name LIKE 'R%'
GO
```

(This, of course, works because R is present in both, so adding a D onto the start is the same as changing the first R into DR. If you want to change R into ST just at the start, then you should perhaps look at [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which is "delete some chars from the string and add another string into the same place", i.e. `STUFF(name, 1, 1, 'ST')` will make `Read` into `STead`. In a similar fashion, if you wanted to convert `Ream` -> `Dream` you can `STUFF(name, 1, 1, 'Dr')` to change the case of the R

Comment: Second query went perfectly, thank you kindly Sir for your time

Comment: If the first letter is not R, then also this second query will concat D to the name. I think you need to test this properly  @Caius Jard

Comment: @Gudwlk see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @CaiusJard oh I missed the wildcard. WHERE Name LIKE 'R%' Sorry abt that.